# Azure Server Script: Push Notification to iOS device: How to set content-available to 1?

Tags: javascript, ios, azure, notifications

Writing a script on Windows Azure cloud to send a Newstand notification to iOS device.
The json body should include content-available set to 1.
What is the syntax to set this property?

My code is below, however, when the notification arrives at the iOS device, the content-available is not present in the aps object.

push.apns.send(item.deviceid, {
                                alert: "Position Check",
                                badge: 1,
                                'content-available':1,
                                }
                                ...

Answer (score 0):

This question is regarding an Azure Mobile Service script in which NotificationHub support does not yet exist.

Update the code to:

```
push.apns.send(item.deviceid, { alert: "Position Check", badge: 1,
 'contentavailable':1,
 } ...
```